# Sequencer adding distortion/stretching to source clip?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm having a problem where my source footage is being distorted when I add it to the sequencer. There's a thin, vertical strip a few pixels wide running down the left side of the frame that's distorting the original clip.

Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

The source clip is an MPEG-4/H.264 render that does not have this issue present when played back in VLC/other video players. Source clip and active workspace are both 1080x1080.

Thank you for any help. Apologies if this question has already been asked, I had trouble finding the right words to describe the issue!

Cheers!

[image]

Blend File in zip with clip:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JzErHcHh645lSCEXhZf9KnWk6bKolMfO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please add blend file so we can check it out

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JzErHcHh645lSCEXhZf9KnWk6bKolMfO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thank for providing blend file. I cannot see that distortion. What version of Blender r u using? i am using 3.1 and it's looking fine

Comment: Interesting...
I am using 3.0. I tested it in 3.1 and still had distortion. 2.91 did not have distortion so that has solved my issue for now. Thanks for your help Chris!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try different versions of Blender